# Schedule Automatic Server Maintenance [Ubuntu]

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.10 server as a LAMP stack. I access this through a SSH terminal (as I don't have access to the physical box).

My question is, is there a way to setup ubuntu to automatically execute a script at chosen times. Like to schedule automatic maintenance scripts that have been built in PHP or really any language (possibly Bash Scripts?). I'm sure this has to be possible.

Since I am a bit newer to linux/ubuntu, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
This is one solution I found if anybody else stumbles across this...

```
sudo crontab -e
...
@daily /usr/bin/wget -q -O /var/log/maintenence.txt /var/www/admin/script.php
```

Comment: `crontab -e` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the crontab in linux.. That wil suit your purpose.
Cron is a daemon that executes scheduled commands
eg:

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
0        2          12             *               0,6           /usr/bin/find
```

Comment: Does this require Gnome gui?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't know you could run it through bash, when I looked it up I saw mostly gnome tutorials. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay for example.. if you need to run the script file `/home/krizna/backup.sh` every `sunday 12 PM` .. just issue the below command

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and add this line at the end of the file

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
  00        12         *             *                7          /bin/sh /home/krizna/backup.sh
```